# How to resolve the application crashing issue upon running it on windows 10?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2019, windows-10-desktop

I have tried to create an installer with visual studio installer project on windows 10 version 1909 (x64). The application setup is created and works fine in installing the application also I do not face any issue running the application on system.

But if i try to install the application on other system with windows 10 version 1909(x64), it installs the application sucessfully on that system as well. But when I run the application it gets abruptly closed without giving any errors.

I have tried looking for the windows logs then I see an error with the error code 0xc0000409. I have tried the possible solutions for this error available on the internet like clean boot or running system file checker but nothing seems to work on that system.

What could be possibly going wrong , please help..

Comment: I'd assume it's a bug in your application, not in Windows. Possibly some *undefined behavior* in your code

Comment: Maybe you need to install the latest (or appropriate) VC Redistributable on the target machine?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: Suggest compiling your application with debugging info.  Then on the target machine use a debugger and when the application crashes, show the backtrace to see both how the application got there and exactly where is crashed.

Comment: please read [win 10 error code 0xc0000409](https://windowsreport.com/0xc0000409-error/)  which discusses how to fix that registry problem

Comment: I have tried to resolve the win 10 error code 0xc0000409 but with no luck.. the application runs fine on other win 10 systems (win 10v 1909 build 18363.720)but facing this problem only on one system with win 10 v1909 build18363.756.

Comment: i know it's an old question, but maybe could be you forget to put all dependancies in the same directory of your app...